# Method 'isChecked()' recurses infinitely, and can only end by throwing an exception

Tags: java, android, menu, drawer

I have this warning but i dont know how to fix it.
When i Start the app it goes in overflow but i can' t resolve the error. Look at the pictures

[DrawerItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAppa.png)

[use the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi4Ss.png)

[main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNrSg.png)

Comment: isChecked() is calling isChecked().  That's an infinite loop.

Comment: Hello and welcome. For the future, code is text. Please post it as such inside the question, not as pictures.

Comment: How i can do the function?

Answer (score 2):

You're invoking the same function when you return. It makes the program keep calling the function every time.

```
public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked(); //notice here that you return a function call, and
    //your program will keep calling it as a return.
}
```

Comment: How i can do the function?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change isChecked to return the property instead of invoking itself recursively.

```
public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}
```